# PHP: simplexml_load_string

Tags: php, simplexml

Using PHP's `simplexml_load_string` how do I get the values of a tag has a particular attribute set to a particular value?

Comment: possible duplicate of [php: parsing table structure with SimpleXML](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1730428/php-parsing-table-structure-with-simplexml)

Answer (score 1):

Once you have loaded your XML data, you should be able to use the [**`SimpleXMLElement::xpath`**](http://fr.php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.xpath.php) method to do an XPath query on it, to find a specific element.

For example, considering your have an XML String, and load it this way :

```
$xmlString = <<<TEST
<root>
    <elt plop="test">aaa</elt>
    <elt plop="huhu">bbb</elt>
</root>
TEST;

$xml = simplexml_load_string($xmlString);
```

You could use the following portion of code to find the `<elt>` tag for which the `plop` attribute has the value `huhu` :

```
$elt = $xml->xpath('//elt[@plop="huhu"]');
var_dump($elt);
```

And you'd get this kind of output :

```
array
  0 => 
    object(SimpleXMLElement)[2]
      public '@attributes' => 
        array
          'plop' => string 'huhu' (length=4)
      string 'bbb' (length=3)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    <?php
// heredoc use
    $string = <<<XML  
    <?xml version='1.0'?> 
    <document>
     <title>Forty What?</title>
     <from>Joe</from>
     <to>Jane</to>
     <body>
      I know that's the answer -- but what's the question?
     </body>
    </document>
    XML;

    $xml = simplexml_load_string($string);
    echo $xml->title; // you can get "Forty What?" value`enter code here`
    ?>
```